# Existence of classical Dirichlet series from Lebesgue integrable inverse Mellin transform

Tags: number-theory, reference-request, dirichlet-series, mellin-transform

Let $f(s)$ be meromorphic in $\mathbb{C}$. Let the following inverse Mellin transform be Lebesgue integrable for all real positive $x$ at some complex point $s$ with some real $c$:

$\frac{1}{2\pi i} \int\limits_{c-i\infty}^{c+i\infty} f(s+w)\frac{x^w}{w}dw$

Does the associated classical Dirichlet series of the form $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n n^{-s}$ exist, such that for all real positive $x$

$\sum_{n\leq x} \frac{a_n}{n^s}=\frac{1}{2\pi i} \int\limits_{c-i\infty}^{c+i\infty} f(s+w)\frac{x^w}{w}dw$

If so, under what conditions on $f(s)$? Any book reference?

Edit1: Let $s$ and $w$ be independent complex variables and let the above integral be Lebesgue integrable on open strips $r_1<\Re s < r_2$ and $R_1<\Re w < R_2$.

Comment: Your question is unclear. If $w \mapsto \frac{f(s+w)}{w}$ is analytic and $L^1$ on the vertical lines $\Re(w) \in (c-a,c+a)$ then $h(x) = \frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_{-i\infty}^{c+i\infty}  \frac{f(s+w)}{w} x^wdw$ is **continuous** (so it is not the partial sums of a Dirichlet series) and has decay $h(e^u) = O(e^{-(a-\epsilon)|u|})$ and $\frac{f(s+w)}{w} = \int_0^\infty x^{-w-1}h(x)dx$ for $\Re(w) \in (c-a,c+a)$. If $\frac{f(s+w)}{w}$ is only $L^1$ or $L^2$ or $L^\infty$ on one vertical line then the latter Mellin transform converges in the sense of distributions.

Comment: If $w \mapsto f(s+w)$ is a Dirichlet series which converges absolutely for $\Re(w) > d  \ge 0$ then $\frac{f(s+w)}{w}$ is $L^2$ on vertical lines $\Re(w) > d$ and it $\to 0$ uniformly as $\Re(w) \to \infty$. From such conditions on $f$ then $h(x) x^{-d-\epsilon}$ is $L^2$ and supported on $x \ge 1$ and there is no obvious way to check if $h$ is constant on intervals $(n,n+1)$ ie. that $f$ is a Dirichlet series.

Comment: Hi! Well, I'm looking for a converse of Titchmarsh's Lemma 3.12 on p.60 from the second edition of his book "The theory of the Riemann zeta-function", https://zulfahmed.files.wordpress.com/2018/08/titchmarsh-and-d-r-heath-brown-the-theory-of-the-riemann-zeta-function.pdf . In Lemma 3.12 we know that $f(s)$ is a Dirichlet series. My question is: if we know $f(s)$ is meromorphic and the inverse Mellin transform above of f(s+w)/w is $L^1$ or $L^2$ or generally $L^p$, does that imply $f(s)$ is a Dirichlet series?

Comment: This is what I answered to. Titchmarsh is assuming $f$ is a Dirichlet series converging absolutely for $\Re(s) > 1$ with some analytic continuation to the left of $\Re(s)=1$

Comment: Indeed. But... We can construct the Dirichlet series above from $f(s)$ recursively. For instance, $a_1=\frac{1}{2\pi i} \int\limits_{c-i\infty}^{c+i\infty} f(s+w)\frac{1^w}{w}dw$, which exists since the integral is Lebesgue integrable for any $x$ at given $s$. Then, one finds $a_2$ from $a_1+a_2/2^s=\frac{1}{2\pi i} \int\limits_{c-i\infty}^{c+i\infty} f(s+w)\frac{2^w}{w}dw$. And so on. Does this help in any way?

Comment: **NO.** $h$ is the unique inverse Mellin transform of $f(s+w)/w$ (in the domain of convergence). Iff it is not supported on $x\ge 1$ and constant on intervals $(n,n+1)$ then $f$ is not a Dirichlet series.

Comment: Indeed. I can see that characters $a_n$ constructed this way need not necessarily be constant, but instead functions of $s$. Not every inverse Mellin transform is a Dirichlet series, that's true. Well, this was quick! Thanks for your replies! Looking forward!

Comment: Not at all, you need to read all my comments again. Start from any continuous function $h$ decreasing fast enough but not constant on intervals $(n,n+1)$ then $$w\int_0^\infty h(\lfloor x\rfloor)x^{-w-1}dx= \sum_{n=1}^\infty (h(n)-h(n-1))n^{-s}$$ is a Dirichlet series  but $w\int_0^\infty h( x)x^{-w-1}dx$ is not. In your post $s$ is constant.

Comment: Could you expand on this idea further, please? Yes, I keep reading, but something seems to miss me so far... Edit: I can see early part of a reply before the reply is completed, I guess. I first read only the first sentence of your last reply. This explains my hastened reply. Looking into into some more, thanks!

Comment: what happens if $s$ is not constant? Because it's not meant to be, the integral should be $L^p$ in a vertical strip $r_1<\Re s<r_2$...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is unclear. If $w \mapsto \frac{f(s+w)}{w}$ is analytic and $L^1$ on the vertical lines $\Re(w) \in (c-a,c+a)$ then $h(x) = \frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_{-i\infty}^{c+i\infty}  \frac{f(s+w)}{w} x^wdw$ is **continuous** (so it is not the partial sums of a Dirichlet series) and has decay $h(e^u) = O(e^{-(a-\epsilon)|u|})$ and $\frac{f(s+w)}{w} = \int_0^\infty x^{-w-1}h(x)dx$ for $\Re(w) \in (c-a,c+a)$. If $\frac{f(s+w)}{w}$ is only $L^1$ or $L^2$ or $L^\infty$ on one vertical line then the latter Mellin transform exists in the $L^2$ sense  or in the sense of distributions.

If $w \mapsto f(s+w)$ is a Dirichlet series which converges absolutely for $\Re(w) > d  \ge 0$ then $\frac{f(s+w)}{w}$ is $L^2$ on vertical lines $\Re(w) > d$ and it $\to 0$ uniformly as $\Re(w) \to \infty$. From such conditions on $f$ then $h(x) x^{-d-\epsilon}$ is $L^2$ and supported on $x \ge 1$ and there is no obvious way to check if $h$ is constant on intervals $(n,n+1)$ ie. that $f$ is a Dirichlet series.

Start from any continuous function $h$ decreasing fast enough but not constant on intervals $(n,n+1)$ then $$w\int_0^\infty h(\lfloor x\rfloor)x^{-w-1}dx= \sum_{n=1}^\infty (h(n)-h(n-1))n^{-w}$$ is a Dirichlet series  but $w\int_0^\infty h( x)x^{-w-1}dx$ is not. In your post $s$ is constant.

Once $h$ the inverse Mellin transform of $F(w)=f(s+w)/w$ exists then $F,h$ are uniquely determined by each other (up to the problem of domain convergence) and you know $f(w)$ and $f(z+w)/w$ for any $z$.

Comment: But $s$ is not constant, I edited the question. Does that change anything?

Comment: @anonymous I mentioned everything you need. So please read seriously my answer and tell what you don't understand.

Comment: thank you for your answer!